# Creating a sticky note with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a sticky note with Javascript and jQuery. The problem I am having is, that the functions `draggable()` and `deleteNote()` can not be called on the **newly appended elements**. How can I fix this?

EDIT: The ID actually should get an added number, which I'm not sure how to implement, because I don't know how to create a counter. E.g. `newbox1`

My code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wowpatrick/qexRS/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the eventhandlers live, since there are no elements existent at the moment you initially called them.

Use jQuerys `live()` (Attention:deprecated [Docu](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) or with new jQuery-version `on()` ([Docu](http://api.jquery.com/on/)), to be able to attach the events on each newly created note.

Also don't use IDs, since this produces invalid markup because IDs always have to be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Could you give me a short example how to use the `on()` to enable the function (e.g. `deleteNote()`) when the element is added?

Comment: @wowpatrick The good thing is, that if you use on, you don't need to mind if new elements are added, it can just attach the listener like `live()` does. Take a look at the jQueryDocu: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `.click` handlers to the new element after you create it.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t create multiple elements with the same ID, use class instead.

Also, you can attach the `.draggable()` to the created element right away instead of targeting `$('#newbox')`.

Here is a fork that works better: http://jsfiddle.net/YvtLb/

The key is here:

```
var postit = $('<div class="ui-widget-content newbox" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><span id="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>').draggable();
$('#canvas').append(postit);
```

Comment: But what about the `deleteNote()` function? How can I get that to work even though it has to be called when a newly appended element is clicked?

Comment: You can delegate it to the document: `$(document).on('click', '#close', function() { // delete`

Answer (score 0):

This is because on page load `#newbox` does not exist. A better method would be to store your new element in a variable, append it, then apply `draggable`, try this:

```
// Create the new comment at the corsor postition
var $newbox = $('<div class="ui-widget-content" id="newbox" style="top:' + e.pageY + 'px; left: ' + e.pageX + 'px;"><span id="close">Delete comment</span><p>Your comment:</p><textarea></textarea></div>');
$('#canvas').append($newbox);
$newbox.draggable();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qexRS/5/)

Comment: I get what you are saying, but on the example you give, the function `deleteNote()` still doesn't seem to work ...